# How to write xelement value as comma separated into another xelement

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

In xslt 1.0 ,I would like to write Delivery Method as comma separated value into another XElement or variable

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <GenerateID>Y</GenerateID>
    <DeliveryMethods>
    <DeliveryMethod>Postal</DeliveryMethod>
    <DeliveryMethod>Mail</DeliveryMethod>
    </DeliveryMethods>
    <OrderIdentity>1FTHX26FXVEA28985</OrderIdentity>
    <Price>100</Price>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

Tried this

```
<xsl:variable name="DeliveryOptions>
<xsl:for-each select="DeliveryMethods/DeliveryMethod">
   <xsl:value-of select="DeliveryMethod"/>
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl-variable>
```

But it is not working. Any help much appreciated?

Comment: Hard to say since we don't know what the context is for the `xsl:variable` and you don't tell us what "But it is not working" really means, but try changing your `xsl:value-of` to `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Comment: I need to tranform this to another xslt so took variable help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT to transform your input to the output replacing one element with the comma delimited values of the child elements:

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DeliveryMethods">
    <allmethods>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="DeliveryMethod"/>
    </allmethods>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DeliveryMethod">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

I use one template to match the `DeliveryMethods` element. In the template the new name for the element is written to the output document.
Next I apply the template for the `DeliveryMethod` elements.

In the template `DeliveryMethod` the current element value is written to the output. As long as the position() of the element is not equal to the last() write a comma.

On your given input the output of this XSLT is:

> ```
> <Orders>
>   <Order>
>     <Number>1</Number>
>     <GenerateID>Y</GenerateID>
>     <allmethods>Postal,Mail</allmethods>
>     <OrderIdentity>1FTHX26FXVEA28985</OrderIdentity>
>     <Price>100</Price>
>     <Quantity>5</Quantity>
>   </Order>
> </Orders>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<Orders>" +
                  "<Order>" +
                    "<Number>1</Number>" +
                    "<GenerateID>Y</GenerateID>" +
                    "<DeliveryMethods>" +
                    "<DeliveryMethod>Postal</DeliveryMethod>" +
                    "<DeliveryMethod>Mail</DeliveryMethod>" +
                    "</DeliveryMethods>" +
                    "<OrderIdentity>1FTHX26FXVEA28985</OrderIdentity>" +
                    "<Price>100</Price>" +
                    "<Quantity>5</Quantity>" +
                  "</Order>" +
                "</Orders>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement deliverMethod = new XElement("DeliveryMethod",string.Join(",",doc.Descendants("DeliveryMethod").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I am tranforming this xslt to another xslt . So it wont work